# CUDA device to host data transfer error

Tags: cuda, memcpy

I have a problem retrieving device data to host.. 
In the sample program below.. I made a hostData array in host and provided values to it.
I then trasfer the hostData to deviceData variable and again transfered the same data to new host data array ie. hostDataFinal. and when I printed the values stored in hostDataFinal upto few values the output is ok rest is shown as garbage value. All the value should be same as in   hostData array. Please Help me with it.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int totalData = 20;
int *hostData;
hostData = new int[totalData];
std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"HostData Values : "<<std::endl;
for (int i=0; i<totalData ;i++)
{
    hostData[i]= i+1;
    std::cout<<hostData[i]<<" "; 
}

int *deviceData;
int *hostDataFinal;
cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceData,totalData*sizeof(int));
hostDataFinal = new int[totalData];

cudaMemcpy(deviceData,hostData,totalData,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(hostDataFinal,deviceData,totalData,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl<<"HostDataFinal After Device Transfer Values : "<<std::endl;
for (int i=0; i<totalData ;i++)
{
    std::cout<<hostDataFinal[i]<<" "; 
}

free(hostData);
free(hostDataFinal);
cudaFree(deviceData);
return 0;
```

}

Output of the Program :

HostData Values :
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

HostDataFinal After Device Transfer Values :

1 2 3 4 5 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451

Actual Output should be :

HostData Values :
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

HostDataFinal After Device Transfer Values :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in these lines. The third parameter in the `cudaMemcpy` is the number of bytes to be copied.

```
cudaMemcpy(deviceData,hostData,totalData,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(hostDataFinal,deviceData,totalData,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

should be

```
cudaMemcpy(deviceData,hostData,totalData *sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(hostDataFinal,deviceData,totalData*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Also make sure you handle return error codes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)

Comment: If your problem is solved, could you consider accepting the answer.